# Windows: How to list all the files in directory and sub directory with full path and creation date

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, dir

I am using the below command but its giving only the full path of the files and not the creation date.

Is there any way I can get the full path with creation date also.

```
             dir /s /b
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dir /s /T:C
```

I got it using `dir /?`